# Share link preview not displaying in whatsapp desktop

Tags: meta-tags

I have a website where I have properly set the OG tags, and where I share one of the pages on WhatsApp for android it properly displays the preview.

However, when using WhatsApp for desktop, the preview is not displayed, all I have is the naked link. I can't pinpoint the issue. Here's an example of one of the pages with the og tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.defiendetumarca.cl/es/blog/que-es-una-marca.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"  content="¿Qué es una marca?" />
<meta property="og:description" content="¿Qué es una marca? ¿Qué tipos de marcas existen? ¿Para qué sirve una marca registrada? Te aclaramos todo en este artículo." />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://www.defiendetumarca.cl/images/logo-chico-blanco.png" />
```

When I share it on WhatsApp for Android, the preview is displayed. But on desktop, it doesn't. I set also the Twitter cards just in case, to no avail. What may be the problem?

EDIT: Here are some websites that the link preview is properly displayed when shared on Whatsapp for desktop:
https://www.biobiochile.cl/
https://www.duplos.cl/
https://www.textual.cl/

Comment: I suspect this is a problem on WhatsApp's end.   We have another similar question that was just asked: [WhatsApp Web does not unfurl link on my website when sharing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137387/whatsapp-web-does-not-unfurl-link-on-my-website-when-sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem where a link to my website is static and does not unfurl on WhatsApp Web, but the same link unfurls on the iOS app. Looking at the server logs at the time of sharing, WhatsApp Web does not even make a request to my website for that page. That page contains the meta tag with a link to the asset. So the problem is not the meta tag syntax.

I shared the pages of the most visited websites (Google, Facebook, Apple, Wikipedia, Youtube) and they **do** unfurl. I suspect that WhatsApp Web filters the links before checking whether they get unfurled with an image preview and a caption. Looking at the history of my messages on WhatsApp Web starting in February 2021, I could not find any occasion with an image associated with a link to my website. So this issue seems to be a bug or a feature.

I reported the bug to WhatsApp [by email](https://www.indiatoday.in/technology/news/story/whatsapp-users-can-now-submit-bug-reports-from-the-app-1731500-2020-10-14). You may want to report it from within the Android app or from WhatsApp Web (`Menu > Settings > Help > Contact Us` on PC or `WhatsApp > Preferences > Help > Contact Us` on Mac). In my experience with Facebook, they do not address bug reports for months, if ever. You may have a better chance if you have a business account.

Comment: Yes, the weird thing is that other links from random pages do have a preview. So I really don't know what the difference is. I've tried looking at their code but found nothing.

Comment: Can you update the question with some of those random pages?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the web version code and found that it's not actually using OG tags, or making any requests whatsoever.

It just has a 700-item list of common URL suffixes (ex: .com, .gov. .eu) that are considered a valid URL.

If the pasted link starts with HTTP/HTTPS and ends with one of those valid suffixes, it displays in link format, regardless if the website exists or not.

Comment: The actual file that holds the validation code is app.77ee8aa7a4c593101105.js, but that can change. Make a search for ''gov'' and you will find the strings.